# Equivalent function to Excel's BETADIST() in R

Tags: r, excel, beta-distribution

I am looking for the equivalent function to BETADIST(). I tried dbeta and dbetadist but these do not give the same result as Excel's BETADIST.

```
BETADIST(1/13,2,4) = 0.050583
dbeta(1/13,2,4, log=F) = 1.210042
```

What did I miss? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try `pbeta(1/13,2,4, log=F)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dbeta` gives the probability density. To match `BETADIST` you need `pbeta`

```
pbeta(1/13,2,4, log=F)
[1] 0.05058269
```